# How should I call a function from model in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm build an application with Laravel which is new for me and I want to create any method in model and i will call that method from those model in some Controller but I don't know it is good or follow Laravel structure or not because Codeigniter let developer do that thing.

How can I use this structure with Eloquent instead of using **raw sql** query? 
because I got no data if I used  `$data = self::select("*")->get();` to query data.

This is my Model

```
    <?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: SOPHEAK Heng
 * Date: 16/03/31
 * Time: 10:29 AM
 * Notification Module
 */

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
class Notification extends Model {

    protected $table = 'notification';
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function __construct(array $attributes)
    {
        parent::__construct($attributes);
    }
     public static function queryData() {

    $data = self::all();
    return $data;
    }
}
```

Here is **Controller:**

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: SOPHEAK Heng
 * Date: 5/25/2015
 * Time: 5:40 PM
 */

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Models\Notification;

class MyController extends Controller
{ 

    public function __construct()
    { 
        $t = $this->sendDataToView();
        var_dump($t);
    }
    public function sendDataToView() {

        $test = new Notification();
        return $test->queryData();
    }

}
```

Here is my result when I have try to used **Eloquent**
It seem known that tables but can't see any data at there
[image]

Comment: Why not create another function for this `DB::table($this->table)`?

Comment: I don't want to used DB I want to used Eloquent instead of using raw sql query.

Comment: `public function queryData()` make it static `public static function queryData()` then call `Notification::queryData()`? is this what you want?

Comment: public static function queryData() {
 
        $data = self::all();
        return $data;
    }

But I can't get data from dB

Comment: `all()` this is in the back end of laravel in the Eloquent Facade.

Comment: Yes so mean that I can't used it inside of model right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107815/discussion-between-heng-sopheak-and-aldrin27).

Comment: Yes you can't so you'll create that yourself.

Comment: Should you tell me some reason why can't used Eloquent inside model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have using mistaken to model and controller in laravel.You should use scope
Model and Controller should be in this way

Model

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class Notification extends Model {

    protected $table = 'notification';
    public $timestamps = false;



   public function scopeData($query)
    {
        return $query->where('done', 1);
    }


}
```

Controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Models\Notification;

class MyController extends Controller
{ 
    public function __construct()
    { 

    }
    public function sendDataToView() {
    $notification =  Notification::data()->get();
    return view('view file',compact('notification'));

    }

}
```

View File

```
 @foreach($notification as $noty)
  $noty->foo
 @endforeach
```

I hope it would be help to you

Comment: NOOOOOOOOO I don't think it is good to used query statement in Controller It should be used in Model and call that method in Controller.

Comment: As my about structure I can call that method in Model by Obj

$obj = new Notification();
        $t = $obj->queryData();
and send to view it will work as well

Comment: ok I advice that you research stuffs such as scopes,repository pattern,query builder for laravel

Comment: should you advice me some idea with my current structure because I don't want to used sql sentence in Controller it make my controller messy and it should be keep in each model or not?

Comment: here, for this you should use repository pattern, which provides to separating model with controller to each other

Comment: I just used this 
$this->_obj = new Notification(); in my constructor of its controller and than call that object 
$t = $this->_obj->queryData();
        return $this->view('teller.chiefofteller',['t'=>$t]);
Now it work as well so what is difference between repository sorry because I don't understand repository yet

Comment: Repository pattern is a very broad. you should research it only you able to learn in this way